# How to hook into a framework(CoreLocation) with Theos/Logos

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, theos

Is it possible to hook into a framework, e.g. CoreLocation, so that all the apps that link to the framework see the patch?

Currently I can hook into a specific app by the following steps:

- create a `iphone/tweak` in Theos
- set the `bundle identifier` to the target app
- call `%hook classname` that interacts with the framework

However this only exposes the tweak to a single app. Can I patch the framework directly? What `bundle identifier` should I use in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every framework has Info.plist file with CFBundleIdentifier key. To hook processes linking to CoreLocation.framework enter `com.apple.corelocation` as bundle filter.